# Shortening Python Lambda

Tags: python-2.7

The code below takes a value and returns it if the value is of basestring. If the the value is not of basestring, then convert it to a string, but if the value is `None`, then return an empty string.

Is there a more Pythonic way of doing this?

```
lambda value: value if isinstance(value, basestring) else str(value) if value is not None else ""
```

Comment: Your question title asks how to 'shorten' this lambda expression, but given the number of different cases you want to handle my feeling is it would be more readable as a fully-fledged function.

Comment: The most unpythonic thing about the current solution is that it implicitly mixes `bytes` and `unicode`.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't even bother checking if it is a string, just convert it regardless (This will work in Python 3.x but not 2.x).

```
lambda value: str(value) if value is not None else ""
```

The reason is that if it is already a `str`, then calling `str()` will basically do nothing.

```
>>> s = 'test'
>>> id(s)
35584672
>>> id(str(s))
35584672
>>> j = str(s)
>>> id(j)
35584672
```

Notice they all have the same `id`? This means no new object was created.

Comment: This breaks for unicode characters, though. `str(u'J\u00e9r\u00e9mie')` --> `UnicodeEncodeError`

Comment: @dennismonsewicz You didn't tag which version of Python you are using. That is only true on Python 2, where you need to use `unicode` instead of `str`. (Although, now I think of it, it could have been inferred since `basestring` does not exist in Python 3.)

Comment: @dennismonsewicz But then your lambda will return sometimes an `unicode` and sometimes a `str`. Which seems incoherent. Is that indeed what you want? Because the simple solution is to use `unicode` everywhere instead of `str(...)`.

Comment: @MariusSiuram - Thanks so much for the suggestion! That's what I think I am going to wind up doing